# Spring Roo finder issue

Tags: spring, spring-roo

I have followed [Spring Roo tutorial](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/05/27/roo-part-2/) (by Ben Alex). Until create finder everything went fine. When I am create `finder` It won't generate generate relevent JSP file. it only update java and .aj file.  What kind of issue this can be?

```
~.domain.Rsvp roo> controller class --class ~.web.PublicRsvpController
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\wedding\web\PublicRsvpController.java
Updated SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP\WEB-INF\i18n\application.properties
Created SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP\WEB-INF\views\publicrsvp
Created SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP\WEB-INF\views\publicrsvp\views.xml
Created SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP\WEB-INF\views\publicrsvp\index.jspx
Updated SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP\WEB-INF\views\menu.jspx
~.domain.Rsvp roo> finder list --class ~.domain.Rsvp --filter code,equ
findRsvpsByAttendingEquals(Integer attending)
findRsvpsByAttendingGreaterThanEquals(Integer attending)
findRsvpsByAttendingLessThanEquals(Integer attending)
findRsvpsByAttendingNotEquals(Integer attending)
findRsvpsByCodeEquals(String code)
findRsvpsByCodeIsNotNull()
findRsvpsByCodeIsNull()
findRsvpsByCodeLike(String code)
findRsvpsByCodeNotEquals(String code)
findRsvpsByConfirmedEquals(Date confirmed)
findRsvpsByConfirmedGreaterThanEquals(Date confirmed)
findRsvpsByConfirmedLessThanEquals(Date confirmed)
findRsvpsByConfirmedNotEquals(Date confirmed)
findRsvpsByEmailEquals(String email)
findRsvpsByEmailNotEquals(String email)
findRsvpsBySpecialRequestsEquals(String specialRequests)
findRsvpsBySpecialRequestsIsNotNull()
findRsvpsBySpecialRequestsIsNull()
findRsvpsBySpecialRequestsLike(String specialRequests)
findRsvpsBySpecialRequestsNotEquals(String specialRequests)

~.domain.Rsvp roo> finder add --finderName findRsvpsByCodeEquals
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\wedding\domain\Rsvp.java
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\wedding\domain\Rsvp_Roo_Finder.aj

~.domain.Rsvp roo>
```

Comment: Please post the particular Spring Roo version you encountered this. Make sure you are using the latest version of Spring Roo.

Comment: I am using `Spring Roo 1.2.0.M1 [rev f27ddd6] log opened at 2011-09-27 11:41:20`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is was Spring Roo document problem, They haven't update their document for Spring Roo 1.2.0 related API changes.

Answer (score 2):

In Roo 1.1.2 is a Bug [[#ROO-2108](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-2108)] that does not generate JSPs for Finder.

And in 1.1.4 there is an other bug: [[#ROO-2480](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-2480)]

But it is fixed in newer Version.

Comment: I am using `Spring Roo 1.2.0.M1 [rev f27ddd6] log opened at 2011-09-27 11:41:20`

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem.

It was just missing this roo command:
**web mvc finder all**

That adds all the necessary finders (:

Answer (score 0):

**web mvc finder all** is the solution for this. 
It worked for me.